# To label different parts of pdf page

Tags: graphics, labels

Assume you have a PDF file with 3x4 pictures.
You want to label each picture.

**How can you label such pictures without cutting manually each picture out separately?**

Next problem is how you can show each steadily separated picture from a pdf-file, but let's concentrate on the first question here only.

Comment: You can include the PDF several times, with suitable values to the `trim` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `overpic` if you wanted to label the images *in situ*. For example, suppose that your PDF looks like this:

[image: 3x4 images]

Then you could use `overpic` to produce this result:

[image: Labelled 3x4 images]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage[scale=1]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{overpic}%
    {3x4.pdf}
    \put(22,72){Label 1}%
    \put(37,72){Label 2}%
    \put(52,72){Label 3}%
    \put(22,58){Label 4}%
    \put(37,58){Label 5}%
    \put(52,58){Label 6}%
    \put(22,44){Label 7}%
    \put(37,44){Label 8}%
    \put(52,44){Label 9}%
    \put(22,30){Label 10}%
    \put(37,30){Label 11}%
    \put(52,30){Label 12}%
\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

To get the correct coordinates, you can use `overpic`'s `grid` option. Replace the line

```
\begin{overpic}%
```

by

```
\begin{overpic}[grid,tics=5]% use this to figure correct coordinates
```

adjusting as necessary to get the size and coarseness of grid required. Mine looked like this after I had added the labels:

[image: Labelled 3x4 images on grid]

Comment: Great answer with nice explanation about grids! I opened a new question based on your answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231166/13173